# How to skip a 13 error (type doesn't match) when running a loop with a conditional?

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, skip

I have the following code to delete rows in which column 8 is equal to 0 and column 4 is 12 characters long:

```
Sub deletezeros()

Dim i As Integer
Dim isin As String
Dim valor As Long
Dim longitud As Long

Worksheets("2. Con.EMISION").Activate

For i = 200 To 1 Step -1

    isin = Cells(i, 4).Value
    longitud = Len(isin)
    valor = Cells(i, 8).Value

    If valor = 0 And longitud = 12 Then
        Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The problema is that, when the loop arrives to a certain row, the `valor` content doesn't fit into a long variable, and then I get

> 13 error: Tpyes doesn't match

¿Is there a way for making the loop skip this loop repetition with a conditional or something for it to keep looping without stopping in cases like this?

Comment: You can always check if the type matches first

Comment: Compare as string instead of long?

Comment: @Taelsin do you mean doing it throught a conditional or something like that?

Comment: @Alex K. If I do that I get the same error, because some of the column 8 cells are strings and others are longs.

Comment: If a cell contains an `Error` value, then it can't be compared to a string or number without throwing runtime error 13 / type mismatch. `IsError` would return `True` for such a cell value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isNumeric` to check if it's a number. If it returns `True`, then skip it. Else you can proceed.

Also, I strongly recommend that you get rid of the `.Activate` on your worksheet, and declare your worksheet and use that declaration instead.

See your code modifications below:

```
Sub deletezeros()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim isin As String
    Dim valor As Long
    Dim longitud As Long

    'Declare your worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2. Con.EMISION")

    'Avoid using .Activate in lieu of using ws
    Worksheets("2. Con.EMISION").Activate

    'Use With ws (optional) for better code clarity
    With ws
        For i = 200 To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 4)) = False Then
                isin = .Cells(i, 4).Value
                longitud = Len(isin)
                valor = .Cells(i, 8).Value

                If valor = 0 And longitud = 12 Then
                    .Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```